# tsconfig has set paths but doesn't compile alias

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

When I compiled the code using tsc, I found that my alias name had not been converted, but I had already configured Paths,Here is tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/1061
    "target": "ES5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "doc/*": ["./site/*"],
      "docs/*": ["./site/Components/*"],
      "ethan/*": ["./src/*"],
      "ethan": ["./src/index.ts"]
    },
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "publish/css",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "alwaysStrict": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "ssh-client", "webpack", "scripts", "docs-pages","publish"]
}
```

One of the compiled file parts of the code is here

```
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.getLocale = exports.setLocale = void 0;
// @ts-nocheck 
var objects_1 = require("@/utils/objects");
```

Where is my code wrong

Thanks~~~

Comment: Please pay attention to correct capitalisation.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have to install additional dependencies for that like [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) or [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths)

> [In my opinion](https://medium.com/@VincentSchoener/say-bye-to-relative-paths-in-typescript-7242b6e6f252), it would be easier to have the path resolved during the compilation but as the TS team says, it gets complicated in some environment with symlink usage.